# How to retain selection after command run (indent-code-rigidly)?

Tags: indentation, region, commands

I found a neat code snippet for `~/.emacs` configuration:

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "C->") 
                  (lambda (b e &optional n) 
                    (interactive "r")
                    (indent-code-rigidly b e (or n 4)))
                  )

  (global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 
                  (lambda (b e &optional n) 
                    (interactive "r")
                    (indent-code-rigidly b e (or n (- 0 4))))
                  )
```

This snippet allows me to use `C->`/`C-<` hotkeys to force indent/unindent selected code block.
But after indent/uindent applies to code block, selection is lost. How to retain selection (or select again same code lines) programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is really what you want:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 
        (lambda (b e n) 
          (interactive "r\nP")
          (indent-code-rigidly b e (if n (prefix-numeric-value n) -4))
          (setq deactivate-mark  nil)))
```

What you were missing was `(setq deactivate-mark  nil)`. After each command, the command loop normally deactivates the region, but if you set this variable to `nil` then it does not.

Beyond that, I fixed (according to what I think you wanted) the use of a prefix argument.

Comment: No bare lambdas, please! :)

Comment: @KaushalModi: I intentionally tried to keep the code close to the OP, so s?he could easily see the difference. It's not necessary to use a named function here, and using one might give the impression that it is. But I agree that it is generally better to use named functions in key bindings, hooks, menu items etc.